# Restrict thousand separator in TO_NUMBER (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I'm trying to parse numbers using the following code

```
TO_NUMBER('1,234.56', '9999999D99')
```

For some reason comma is ignored and the value is parsed correctly, despite the format doesn't have it. Is there any way to restrict usage of thousand group separator?

So far I only came up with setting a bogus symbol as a separator with the hope that user will not use it

```
TO_NUMBER('1,234.56', '9999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.ã''');
```

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: `if instr(:inputvalue,',')>0 then raise_application_error(-20000,'Commas are not allowed, even though they hurt no-one'); end if;`

Comment: The problem is that we need to support user input numbers in certain format, which is up to n digits before point, and up to m digits after. We don't want any commas. The format that I use in the function call doesn't include the group separator indicator. But the thing still allows commas, anywhere in the number. Later in the code the string fails to automatically convert to a number(n+m, m). I consider it a bug in Oracle.

Comment: It sounds as though you're storing numbers as strings and then are surprised when Oracle doesn't implicitly convert correctly. What's stopping you from converting to a number in the beginning (and stripping out the commas) and then using only numbers stores as numbers?

Comment: @Ben I think I'm being very explicit providing Oracle the exact format, in which I expect numbers to be stored, however Oracle prefers to make its own assumptions instead. I need to store user input as text in the DB and validate it there using set of rules before converting to numbers, references etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange request - if Oracle is correctly converting the string to a number then it seems to be doing it's job correctly. However, if you *really* need to do this for whatever reason then simply remove the format mask.

```
SQL> select to_number('1,234.56') from dual;
select to_number('1,234.56') from dual
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number


SQL> select to_number('1234.56') from dual;

TO_NUMBER('1234.56')
--------------------
             1234.56

SQL>
```

Though the [SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm#i79512) doesn't mention any default values I believe that the default value for the format mask described in the [OLAP DML Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2117.htm#OLADM695) for `TO_NUMBER()` applies:

> The default number format identifies a period (.) as the decimal marker and does not recognize any other symbol.

This, in turn, means that a comma is an invalid value for the conversion and thus the conversion will fail.

Comment: Unfortunately this signature doesn't check precision. Thanks for the answer anyways

Comment: But why does it accept commas even if there is no comma in the format string ? I tried with both '0' and '9' format both are accepting commas even if there is no comma in the format string.

Comment: I suspect my answer here is insufficiently rigorous @A_J. It will also depend on your session's values for NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS. The answer was predicated on the OP being in Canada and myself being in the UK. The comma is the decimal separator in other parts of the world and I'd guess you're working on an application where this is the case?

Comment: AFAIK the first character in NLS_CHARACTER is the decimal separator, when I checked mine in Oracle 11g in India it is dot not the comma. But I don't understand how does this relate to accepting comma in the string without giving one in the format string. Kindly reply with @A_J in the beginning so that I am notified of your reply.

Comment: @Ben does this mean that since it does not recognize any other symbol other than dot that's why it is not giving error. But that should be the case when I don't give the format at all as you have described in your answer but when giving the format string it should give the error if comma is there in the string and not in the format. I am still unclear about it. It would be very helpful if you can explain this.